# How to style image-cropping feature inside a modal using material UI?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a decent skill of CSS to postion things in basic page but it's so confusing doing it inside modal.
I have tried using component Dialog from mui-material to wrap the cropper but it didnt work so I use Modal component.

I want to make it something like this but only the cropper section, cancel and crop button. That's it. The buttons are supposed to be outside of the cropper with white background.
[image]

My modal can already functions but it didnt look good yet

[image]

This is my code:

```
// import React, {useRef, useState} from 'react'
// import style from '../App.scss.json'
// import ImageCropper from '../components/ImageCropper'


// const Uploader = () => {
//     const [image, setImage] = useState(null)
//     const [fileName, setFileName] = useState("No profile photo selected")
    
//     return (
//         <form onClick={() => document.querySelector<HTMLElement>(".input-field").click()}>
//             {image ? <img src={image} alt={fileName} className={style.imageUpload}  /> : <img src="/static/images/upload-icon.svg" style={{height: '100px', width: '100px'}} className={style.imageUpload} />}
//             <input 
//                 accept="image/*" 
//                 type="file" 
//                 hidden 
//                 className="input-field" 
                // onChange={({target: {files}}) => {
                //     files[0] && setFileName(files[0].name)
                //     if (files){

                //         setImage(URL.createObjectURL(files[0]))
                //     }
                // }}
//             />
//         </form>
//     )
// }

// export default Uploader

import React, {useRef, useState, useCallback} from 'react'
import style from '../App.scss.json'
import Cropper from 'react-easy-crop'
import Slider from "@material-ui/core/Slider";
import {Dialog, DialogActions, Button, Box, Typography, Modal} from '@mui/material'
import getCroppedImg from '../components/CroppedImage'


const Uploader = () => {
    const [image, setImage] = useState(null)
    const [fileName, setFileName] = useState("No profile photo selected")
    const [croppedArea, setCroppedArea] = useState(null)
    const [crop, setCrop] = useState({x:0, y:0})
    const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(1)

    //modal
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
    const handleOpen = () => {
        setOpen(true);
        triggerFileSelectPopUp()
    }
    const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);

    const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>()
    const triggerFileSelectPopUp = () => inputRef.current.click()

    const onCropComplete = (croppedAreaPercentage, croppedArea) => {
        setCroppedArea(croppedArea);
    };
    
    const showCroppedImage = useCallback(async () => {
        try {
        const croppedImage = await getCroppedImg(
            image,
            croppedArea
        )
        console.log('donee', { croppedImage })
        setCroppedArea(croppedImage)
        handleClose()
        // setOpenCrop(false)
        // setCroppedArea(URL.createObjectURL(blobUrl))
        } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
    }
    }, [image, croppedArea])
    
    const onSelectFile = (event) => {
        if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
            reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
                setImage(reader.result);
            });
        }
    }

    const onCropCancel = () => {
        setImage(null)
        handleClose()
    }

    const zoomPercent = (value) => {
        return `${Math.round(value * 100)}%`;
    };

    return (
        <>
            {image ? ( 
                <Modal open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
                    <div className={style.modal_container}>
                        <div className={style.cropper}>
                            <Cropper 
                                image={image} 
                                crop={crop} 
                                zoom={zoom} 
                                aspect={3/5}
                                onCropChange={setCrop} 
                                onZoomChange={setZoom} 
                                onCropComplete={onCropComplete} 
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className={style.slider_container}>
                            {/* <Box sx={{ width: '100%', mb: 1 }}> */}
                                <Typography>Zoom: {zoomPercent(zoom)}</Typography>
                                <div className={style.slider}>
                                    <Slider 
                                        min={1}
                                        max={3}
                                        step={0.1}
                                        value={zoom}
                                        onChange={(e, zoom:any) => setZoom(zoom)}/>
                                </div>
                            {/* </Box> */}
                        </div>
                        <div className={style.button_container}>
                            <Button onClick={onCropCancel}>Cancel</Button>
                            <Button onClick={showCroppedImage}>Crop</Button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Modal>
            ) : null}
                    <div className={style.image_container}>
                        {image ? <img src={croppedArea ? croppedArea : image} alt={fileName} className={style.imageUpload} onClick={handleOpen} /> : <img src="/static/images/upload-icon.svg" style={{height: '100px', width: '100px'}} className={style.imageUpload} onClick={triggerFileSelectPopUp} />}
                        <input 
                            accept="image/*" 
                            type="file" 
                            hidden 
                            ref={inputRef}
                            className="input-field" 
                            onChange={onSelectFile}
                            onClick={handleOpen}
                        />
                    </div>
                    {/* {croppedArea ? (
                        <img alt="Cropped" style={{ maxWidth: '100%' }} src={croppedArea} />
                    ) : null} */}
        </>
    )
}

export default Uploader
```

This is the CSS

```
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 70vw;
}

.modal_container {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 500px;
  height: 70%;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  box-shadow: 24px;
  padding: 4px;
}

.image_container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

.cropper{
  background-color: red;
}

.slider {
  height: 10%;
}

.slider_container{
  background: white;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: end;
  align-items: center;
}

.disable_cropper {
  display: none;
}

.button_container {
  position: absolute;
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside **DialogContent** you can use **Box** component and make it prettier. Also **Grid** component works very well too.

```
<Box
                alignItems="center"
                justifyContent="center"
                minHeight={400}
                width={"100%"}
                display="flex"
            > 
<ReactCrop
                    crop={crop}
                    onChange={(_, percentCrop) => setCrop(percentCrop)}
                    onComplete={(c) => setCompletedCrop(c)}
                    aspect={3 / 2}
                    minWidth={100}
                    style={{borderRadius: 12}}
                >
                    <img
                        ref={imgRef}
                        alt="Crop me"
                        src={imgSrc}
                        style={{transform: `scale(${scale}) rotate(${rotate}deg)`, borderRadius: 12}}
                        onLoad={onImageLoad}
                    />
                </ReactCrop>

            </Box>
```

[image]